# Can I identify the same values within a range between 2 columns?

Tags: r, compare

I am trying to compare values between two different columns but I need it to accept values within a range of ±3.

I created this 2 tibbles:

```
example_tp1 <- tibble(Object_centre = c(84, 149, 489, 534, 680.5))

example_tp2 <- tibble(Object_centre = c(84.5, 149.5, 489, 528.5, 542, 680.5))
```

And I want the program to link the ones that are the same within a ±3 range.
So for example, I want it to identify that 84 and 84.5 are the same, also 149 and 149.5; 489 and 489; 680.5 and 680.5. But I want it to also tell me that 534, 528.5 and 542 do not have a match.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at all combinations of values and see which ones match.

```
# Data Frame of all combinations
example <- expand.grid(c(84, 149, 489, 534, 680.5), c(84.5, 149.5, 489, 528.5, 542, 680.5))

# Assigns a Match if the values are within a range of 3
example %>% 
  mutate(match = ifelse(abs(Var1-Var2) <= 3, "Match", "No Match"))
```

```
 Var1  Var2    match
1   84.0  84.5    Match
2  149.0  84.5 No Match
3  489.0  84.5 No Match
4  534.0  84.5 No Match
5  680.5  84.5 No Match
6   84.0 149.5 No Match
7  149.0 149.5    Match
8  489.0 149.5 No Match
9  ..... ..... ........
10 ..... ..... ........ 

and so on
```

You could then filter out only the matches or see which values have no match.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved via the `fuzzyjoin` package like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

example_tp1 <- tibble(Object_centre = c(84, 149, 489, 534, 680.5))
example_tp2 <- tibble(Object_centre = c(84.5, 149.5, 489, 528.5, 542, 680.5))

match_fun1 <- function(x, y) {
  # (x >= y - 3) & (x <= y + 3)
  # or following the suggestion by @DarrenTsai
  abs(x - y) <= 3
}

fuzzy_full_join(example_tp1, example_tp2, 
                by = c("Object_centre"), 
                match_fun = match_fun1)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   Object_centre.x Object_centre.y
#>             <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1             84             84.5
#> 2            149            150. 
#> 3            489            489  
#> 4            680.           680. 
#> 5            534             NA  
#> 6             NA            528. 
#> 7             NA            542
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Maybe `abs(x - y) <= 3` is more intuitive than  `(x >= y - 3) & (x <= y + 3)`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai. Thanks. You are absolutely right. Edited my code accordingly. Best

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Jumble's answer using `tidyverse` functions :

```
tidyr::crossing(example_tp1, example_tp2, .name_repair = ~c('col1', 'col2')) %>%
  dplyr::filter(abs(col1 - col2) <= 3)

#   col1  col2
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1   84   84.5
#2  149  150. 
#3  489  489  
#4  680. 680.
```

`crossing` generates all combinations of `example_tp1` and `example_tp2` and we keep only those rows where the difference is less than equal to 3.